# How to call menu Objects from another class Android

Tags: java, android, menu, drawer

I have a class with the Menu and Navigation drawer (navObj class). I would like to call the menu and drawer from my other activity classes.

For example, I want to call the menu on my main activity class using the objects from navObj class.

Here is my navObj class:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

    public void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] drawer_Array = { "User Profile", "Setting", "Contact us", "Help", "Logout" };
    String[] desc_Array = { "Private", "Change settings", "Ask us anything", "Simple Guide", "Logs out user" };
    Integer[] image_Array = { R.drawable.user, R.drawable.setting, R.drawable.contactme, R.drawable.help, R.drawable.logout };

   //mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, drawer_Array);
    //mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < drawer_Array.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(image_Array[i], drawer_Array[i], desc_Array[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    CustomDrawerBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomDrawerBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0){
                Intent toProfile = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), userprofActivity.class);
                startActivity(toProfile);
                //Toast.makeText(getMsgActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            }
            else if(position == 1){
                //Toast.makeText(getMsgActivity.this, "Time for an Wake!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(position == 2){
                //Toast.makeText(getMsgActivity.this, "Time for an Eat!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(position == 3){
                //Toast.makeText(getMsgActivity.this, "Time for an Dance!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(position == 4){
                //Toast.makeText(getMsgActivity.this, "Time for an Sleep!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }   
        }
    });
  }

    public void setupDrawer() {
        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("User Menu Option");
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(listView);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_write).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_grabmsg).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_mydiary).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            System.out.println("landscape");

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            System.out.println("portrait");
        }
    } 
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        //String language_chosen = bundle.getString("lang_pick");

        if (id == R.id.action_write) {
            Intent writeNewMsg = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), writeMsgActivity.class);
            //writeNewMsg.putExtra("lang_pick", language_chosen);
            startActivity(writeNewMsg);
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_grabmsg){
            Intent grabNewMsg = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), getMsgActivity.class);
            //grabNewMsg.putExtra("lang_pick", language_chosen);
            finish();
            startActivity(grabNewMsg);

        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_mydiary){

        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Now I want to call this from another activity class:

```
    navObj nav = new navObj();
    Menu menu = null; //it wants me to make menu null inorder to call the parameters from the navObj class.
    nav.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

So my question is how am I able to call this without passing the parameter of "null" because it will crash my app. Any information is appreciated.

Comment: means you want your navigation drawer for other activity's according to my understanding by reading your question then. please create navObj class as activity and extends  it to your others activity .

Comment: do I still need to call the object if I extends the navObj on my other activities?

Comment: nope inheritance . if you want to change in some other activity override onCreateOptionMenu.

Comment: thanks it worked but i have a new problem with the drawer not opening, it was working before I created the separate object class of its own.